# Exception handling in class constructor

Tags: c#, exception

this case is bothering me since morning. Is it good practice to call garbage collector in class constructor if it throws Exception ? I have something like this:

```
public MyClass(/* some arguments */)
{
    try 
    {
      //do stuff...
    } catch(Exception e) {
      //do stuff, save logfile
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

}
```

The reason that I did it like this is that if it threw Exception (usualy NullreferenceException) I want to log it in text file and I don't need/want this object anymore. but is it good practice? If not how to do it properly?

Comment: Does your class even have a finalizer? If not then calling `GC.SuppressFinalize` is completely pointless.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code doesn't call the garbage collector - it merely suppresses the finalizer, which is only important if your class *has* a finalizer, which is pretty unlikely.

It's fair enough to log the exception, but currently you're just *catching* it, which means the constructor will return with no errors. That's almost certainly not a good idea. I suggest you probably want:

```
try 
{
  //do stuff...
} catch(Exception e) {
  //do stuff, save logfile
  throw;
}
```

Having said that, I would normally try to centralize exception handling anyway, putting it a long way up the call stack and putting all logging in there. It would be pretty rare to put the logging within a constructor, IMO.

Unless you've published the `this` reference from within your constructor, the newly created object will be eligible for garbage collection anyway - you don't need to do anything else. If you implement `IDisposable` in your class you should be careful to release any resources you've already required within the constructor, but in *most* cases you can just let the exception bubble up.